# Rooting Desire permanently

Tags: rooting

If I root my Desire permanently  can I reset it to default manufacturers settings by installing official android version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you root your device, you are adding root access to the current OS. If you just perform the Factory Reset, it will retain root (as this just deletes user data), but if you restore the stock image, it will completely wipe the OS and will put the system back as HTC intended it (which would remove root). You would then need to re-root the device.

Comment: Note that if you replace the original recovery with clockworkmod (or some other recovery), that will *not* get restored if you flash the original image. If you are trying to restore your phone in order to get warranty service done (for example), you'll have to find an image for the original recovery along with the original rom.

Comment: This depends on the manufacturer. I know with previous HTC devices, when you use the RUU, it will completely replace the phone's software including the recovery. Also, if you replace the system image, most OSs will automatically restore the stock recovery on every boot unless you modify the OS to prevent it.

Comment: That's what Stephen was referring to with "original recovery along with the original rom". Sometimes both are bundled, sometimes not.

Comment: what is stock image exactly?

Comment: The stock image is basically a snapshot of the system as HTC intends it to be. This will either be an image file of the exact OS/version that was shipped with your phone, or sometimes they will release newer images from updated versions they've put out.